# Lost a digital copy of patent specification

Tags: law, patent-applications, pct, priority, lawyers

I filed the National phase application on 29th Oct 2014 and PCT application on 14th Oct 2015.

I lost a flash drive which contained the soft-copy of patent specification (everything related to the filing), couple of days before/after (I am not sure) filing a PCT application, but the PCT application has a priority claim which dates to 29th Oct 2014. Will there be a problem ? Should I lodge a police complaint just to be on a safer side ?

I was planning to publish couple of journal papers related to the patent filed. Will there be a problem in future if someone tries to publish it ?